# How do I exit a WPF application programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, shutdown

How is one supposed to exit an application such as when the user clicks on the Exit menu item from the File menu?

I have tried:

```
this.Dispose();
this.Exit();
Application.ShutDown();
Application.Exit();
Application.Dispose();
```

Among many others. Nothing works.

Answer (score 905, accepted):

To exit your application you can call

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

As described in the documentation to the [`Application.Shutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx) method you can also modify the shutdown behavior of your application by specifying a [ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx):

> Shutdown  is implicitly called by Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) in the following situations:
>
> - When ShutdownMode is set to OnLastWindowClose.
> - When the ShutdownMode is set to OnMainWindowClose.
> - When a user ends a session and the SessionEnding event is either unhandled, or handled without cancellation.

Please also note that `Application.Current.Shutdown();` may only be called from the thread that created the `Application` object, i.e. normally the main thread.

Comment: As I pointed out it's not weird. In WPF Application is a static class. Application.Current is a reference to your currently running Application.

Comment: In my opinion, it is a little weird in the sense that this isn't obvious at first glance, and it deviates just enough from past models to throw people off. It makes perfect sense that it works of course.

Comment: Put it simple: because if your last window is closed with...
this.Close()
...The application will be shutdown, provided that you didn't change the ShutdownMode.

Comment: If you call `Application.Current.Shutdown();` your fonction will not return immediately. You need to call `return;` as well for this.

Comment: I have used this where from one window pop up another window and, in that window's window_closed event I added this code. all the windows disappear, but the program still runs beyond where after the pop up is created.

Comment: Is Shutdown supposed to call OnExit? Or do I need to call that?

Comment: @TimothyP No `Application` is NOT a static class. Having a `Application.Current` static member does not mean it is static. Instead, it is an normal class that can be derived.

Answer (score 195):

If you *really* need it to close out you can also use [Environment.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx), but it is not graceful at all (more like ending the process).

Use it as follows:

```
Environment.Exit(0)
```

Comment: `Environment.Exit()` needs at least one parameter, an exit code. Use `Environment.Exit(0)` if you are not concerned about the exit code.

Comment: This method actually closed everything. My app was leaving something running (the form was closing, but a process was still running) with `Application.Current.Shutdown();`

Comment: Environment.Exit is definitely the right way to ensure shutdown of an application. With Application.Current.Shutdown you can easily end up with the application running on indefinitely if you have code that pushes itself back into the dispatcher.

Comment: As equal as Application.exit(0);

Comment: With `Application.Current.Shutdown();` my `Closing` event was called, when I simply wanted to shutdown my app immediately. So `Environment.Exit(0);` was the better choice.

Answer (score 83):

As [wuminqi said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820357/how-do-i-exit-a-wpf-application-programmatically/2824572#2824572), `Application.Current.Shutdown();` is irreversible, and I believe it is typically used to force an application to close at times such as when a user is logging off or shutting down Windows.

Instead, call `this.close()` in your main window. This is the same as pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or the close [x] button on the window. This will cause all other owned windows to close and will end up calling `Application.Current.Shutdown();` so long as the close action wasn't cancelled. Please see the MSDN documentation on [Closing a Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Closing_a_Window).

Also, because `this.close()` is cancellable you can put in a save changes confirmation dialog in the closing event handler. Simply make an event handler for `<Window Closing="...">` and change `e.Cancel` accordingly. (See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Closing_a_Window) for more details on how to do this.)

Comment: +1 I decided to go with this one, especially since I need to save open files before actually quitting the application.

Comment: One important thing to note here is the fact that Allen pointed out a very important fact: all other owned windows will be shut down.  You have to make sure that you declare ownership.  If you have a window that is running and then you open another window but do not show it yet, after you close the active window, the hidden window will force application to keep running.  You will have a potential memory leak unless you close that window through other means (task manager, etc). I've tested this.

Comment: @B.K. so in such a case will using Application.Current.Shutdown() instead of this.close() close the hidden windows as well?

Answer (score 40):

Use any of the following as needed:

**1.**

```
 App.Current.Shutdown();
OR
 Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

**2.**

```
 App.Current.MainWindow.Close();
OR
 Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

Above all methods will call **`closing event`** of **`Window`** class and execution may stop at some point (cause usually applications put dialogues like ***'are you sure?'*** or '***Would you like to save data before closing?***', before a window is closed completely)

**3.** But if you want to terminate the application **without any warning** immediately. Use below

> ```
>    Environment.Exit(0);
> ```

Answer (score 29):

This should do the trick:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

If you're interested, here's some additional material that I found helpful:

[Details on Application.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current.aspx)

[WPF Application LifeCycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743714.aspx#Application_Shutdown)

Answer (score 21):

Summarizing, there are a few ways to do that.

**1)** Killing the process, which skip the finalization, error handling etc.:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

**2)** Shutting down current application, which is probably the proper way because it calls the exit events:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

or

```
this.Shutdown();
```

(when clled in an instance of App-class)

**3)** Closing current app (all forms have to be closed/finished earlier):

```
this.Close();
```

(when called in an instance of App-class)

**4)** Exiting the environment, which terminates the app:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Also, You may want to read about exit statusses [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: "Environment.Exit(0);" worked for me. The most voted answer with "System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();" didn't worked as the application tried to run the next code lines. Upvoted yours. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Here's how I do mine:

```
// Any control that causes the Window.Closing even to trigger.
private void MenuItemExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

// Method to handle the Window.Closing event.
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var response = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit?", "Exiting...",
                                   MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    if (response == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

I only call for `Application.Current.ShutDown()` from the main application window, all other windows use `this.Close()`.  In my main window, `Window_Closing(...)` handles the top right `x` button.  If any of the methods call for window closer, `Window_Closing(...)` grabs the event for shut down if user confirms.

The reason I do in fact use `Application.Current.Shutdown()` in my main window is that I've noticed that if a design mistake was made and I haven't declared a parent of one of my windows in an application, if that window is opened without being shown prior to the last active window closing, I'm left with a hidden window running in the background.  The application will not shut down.  The only way to prevent complete memory leak is for me to go into the *Task Manager* to shut down the application.  `Application.Current.Shutdown()` protects me from unintended design flaws.

That is from my personal experience.  In the end, use what is best for your scenario.  This is just another piece of information.

Answer (score 17):

There should not be an `Application.ShutDown();` or `.Exit()` message.

`Application` is a static class. It does not refer to the current application.
You need to get to the current application and then shut it down like this:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Answer (score 12):

Another way you can do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

This will force kill your application. It always works, even in a multi-threaded application.

Note: Just be careful not to lose unsaved data in another thread.

Comment: This seems incomprehensible: *"in process always works"*. Can you fix it? Or at least explain here in comments what you mean?

Comment: This is also partly incomprehensible: *Just care about an application that has save data in files from another thread.* Can you fix it?  Or at least explain here in comments what you mean?

Comment: Are you using Google Translate?

Comment: no I don't, my mean is when application is running as multi thread and you using Process.Kill it will works,but another way like this.close not working in multithread applications when another thread is running.

Answer (score 7):

According to my understanding, `Application.Current.Shutdown()` also has its drawback.

If you want to show a confirmation window to let users confirm on quit or not, `Application.Current.Shutdown()` is irreversible.

Comment: I don't understand this. We can get user confirmation before calling `Application.Current.Shutdown()` however.

Comment: I don't see why you should confirm. Too many confirmations is a very bad thing. The fact that somebody took the effort to click to open the File menu, move all the way down to the bottom of the File menu and then click Exit, is pretty much confirmed that they no longer wish to use the application.

Comment: Veer: In my case, the confirmation window do appear, but even when you choose "cancel" in the confirmation, the main APP exits.

Comment: J-T-S:This is better to be designed case by case. Our app, if there are jobs running, the force exit will cause damages, so we better to let them informed in the confirmation dialog

Answer (score 7):

```
private void _MenuExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
}

//Override the onClose method in the Application Main window

protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result =   MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close", "",
                                          MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: this is not the question answer he only want to know how to exit wpf application.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
App.Current.Shutdown();
```

For me

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Caliburn micro flavoured

```
public class CloseAppResult : CancelResult
{
    public override void Execute(CoroutineExecutionContext context)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
        base.Execute(context);
    }
}

public class CancelResult : Result
{
    public override void Execute(CoroutineExecutionContext context)
    {
        OnCompleted(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs { WasCancelled = true });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *"Caliburn micro flavoured"* mean?

Comment: How you would achieve it using Caliburn Micro

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exit from another thread that didn't create the application object, use: [`System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeshutdown)

Answer (score 2):

`App.Current.Shutdown();`

Write that where you need to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Application.Current.Shutdown()` to exit the application, you may get a `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.` if you are invoking it from a different thread. To solve this, you can wrap the call like this

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Application.Current.Shutdown());
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.MessageLoop) 
{
    // WinForms app
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    system.Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: The question is about WPF. The Environment.Exit() code is all the OP may need, and the exit code 1 could signify an error, as 0 is the standard to convey the program's successful execution.

Answer (score -2):

`Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;`

Comment: Welcome to SO, Alpha-LIon! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Answer (score -3):

From xaml code you can call a predefined SystemCommand:

```
Command="SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand"
```

I think this should be the prefered way...

Comment: Minimize != exit application. I don't see an exit app option in that list. Seems more window management and close window doesn't necessarily mean close app.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396