# Return Value by closing MainWindow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a WPF Application. It´s for testing a process. I start this over a console. When the process ends, the MainWindow will be closed with Window.Close(). Now I try to return a integer value when my program closes. It is possible to see this value in my console?

For example in Java has the method System.Exit(1). Then I can see the return value on my console. But is it possible in WPF Applications?

Maybe this is also the solution bottle and somebody has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown(1);
```

See this question for more info:
[How to exit a WPF app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820357/how-to-exit-a-wpf-app-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can call `Environment.Exit(code)`

[msdn Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)