# Dialog.Close() in MVVM context without error message

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

I would like to know how i can exit my application using MVVM

I have tried `App.Current.Shutdown();` but I have the folowing output : `MyProgram has stop working`

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Can you post more details? Like the full exception details and where it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the correct method, however depending upon which mode you have your `ShutDownMode` set to, you'll need to make sure that either your Main Window is closed, or if you have it set to `OnLastWindowClosed`, then all your windows must be closed prior to shutting down your application.

This answer explains the detail a little bit more;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820377/1305169

Answer (score 2):

The view model that your main window sees needs to publish an event using your chosen mechanism. The main window should listen for this event and close when it sees it.

It is important that you also send a message to other areas of the system to notify of the shutdown. This way you can ensure that non-daemon threads are shutdown and that all unmanaged handles are closed. For any filestreams you may have open, this is the appropriate opportunity to flush your stream!