# Application not ending properly and running in the background

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have a simple wpf application. But it is using CefSharp to open some links in chrome based browser. I found that once the main window of the application is closed, It is closed from the UI but it still runs in the background.

I tried adding additional code to force close it. but no hope. I think some components of cefsharp is not ending correctly. but not exactly sure on what is going wrong.

Used the below code and some other snippets too

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);


            foreach (Window w in App.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (w.DataContext != this)
                    w.Close();
            }
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```

Comment: try `Cef.Shutdown();`

Comment: cool. it works!

Comment: Happy to help :) - found the answer here https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/990

Comment: i tried, it is not allowing me.. need to wait few mins. i will do it in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, try: `Environment.Exit(0);`

If that doesn't work, start with `Cef.Shutdown();`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9050477/1274820

> If you REALLY need it to close out you can also use Environment.Exit() but it is not graceful at all (more like ending the process).

Comment: yes i tried this. but its still running when i check the task manager

Comment: try `Cef.Shutdown();`